# Синхронизация: чтение после записи

Tags: многопоточность, синхронизация

Есть семь параллельных  потоков, каждый переписывает одну строчку матрицы. Как блокировать чтение из матрицы после записи ? Взять стандартный семафор?
Пишу на C++ Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 3):

Почему "после записи"? Может быть "во время"?

Вы не указали тэг для языка, поэтому ответ будет общим. Варианта два:

- Если ваш язык/платформа поддерживает read-write lock, используйте его. Он позволяет нескольким потокам читать данные, но писать может только один поток. И во время записи никто читать не может.
- Если read-write lock'а у вас нет, используйте семафор(1).

Comment: Хорошо, наверное неверно выразился, допустим в каждом отдельном потоке у меня формируется отдельная строчка матрицы. Пока эти семь потоков не сработали, поток работы с матрицей блокируются. И наоборот, пока матрица не отработана, блокировать перепись матриц, это возможно?